Can't access Organization in Azure Devops
I have added a user to an existing organization on Azure DevOps as shown below:

However, when the user logs into DevOps, they can't access any organization. It just keeps loading forever:

Has anyone else encountered this issue?
Please help me fix this.

Have you granted user permissions for that user in specific project?

Can you let the user open an InPrivate window to go to the organization URL https://dev.azure.com/orgname/  directly and see if there will be any error message?


Let the user open an InPrivate window to go to the organization URL https://dev.azure.com/orgname/ directly

You should make sure that the user selects the corresponding directory. The user can sign in to the Azure DevOps profile page and select/switch the Directory from the dropdown list in the left panel.




More steps the invited user can try:


Open browser to aka.ms/vssignout and let it complete
Navigate to aka.ms/vssignout?wa=wsignoutcleanup1.0 and let it complete. You should see a tiny checkmark and nothing else.
Delete cookies (press CTRL+SHIFT+DEL in most browsers)
Close browser and reopen in a private session
Paste the email verification link into the browser and navigate there.
Sign in when prompted

